# I'm creating a new module with apostrophe cms, How would I populate a select field type with all of the blog posts from apostrophe-blogs

Tags: blogs, apostrophe-cms

I had thought about trying to use a join, but not sure how to connect a select field to populate with all the latest blog postings.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a select field to access blog posts from a schema, I would recommend using a join field pointed at your blog piece type.

Getting started with joins can be found in the documentation here 
http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/schema-guide.html#code-join-by-one-code

You can join to a single piece or an array of pieces by using`joinByOne` and `joinByArray`, respectively.